# How can I connect to a printer through multiple routers?

Tags: router, printer, gateway

My setup looks like the image below.

I want to connect to the printer. I'm going through a Router/Gateway into another Router and finally to my Printer. How would I do this?

[image: My Network Diagram]

Comment: This may or may not be possible depending on the type of router you have. In general, you would have to set up routing (either static or dynamically generated) to forward traffic between the routers.

Answer (score 0):

3 options that are relatively easy if you have full access to the equipment.

You could put the second router into bridging mode if it supports the feature, Connect the printer to the first router or connect your PC to the second.